# Laravel REST Routes with different parameters

Tags: laravel, rest, controller, routes

I'm building a REST application and I have a doubt about the best practice in case of different routes calling the same controller method.

**Example:**

Route::post('/company/{id}/people/store', 'PeopleController@store')

Route::post('/people', 'PeopleController@store')

In the first case, I have an extra parameter $company_id to link the person to the company.
Is it correct, or I should use a different method for each route?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you're storing form data, so just add an extra parameter using hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="company_id" value="{{ $company->id }}">
```

Then in the `store()` method you can get this parameter with:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $companyId = $request->company_id;
```